# What is the Freeciv setting to automatically raze or not when capturing a city?

Tags: freeciv

I've been looking for a freeciv setting that would allow me to choose between razing a city when capturing it and keeping the city. Couldn't find it in the options dialog. I'm asking here to make sure I didn't overlook it.

For now, if I want a city destroyed, I'm using a wave of "Poison city" spy attacks which reduces the population to 1. Then the city gets destroyed when I capture it.

Another way to decrease the population to 1 is using nukes, but this is expensive and has a very negative impact on the ecology, so it doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Freeciv wiki](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Freeciv) cities are only destroyed while at level 1. The [forums also seem weary of this topic](http://forum.freeciv.org/viewtopic.php?t=4166&sid=233b763586b99523dc2a520c73c4da99), which implies it is one of those oft-requested, never-to-be implemented features.

This leaves the conclusion that it is not possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

From the Freeciv issue tracker:

> ... [Freeciv] 3.0 will introduce the "Destroy City" action. Custom rulesets can use it as an alternative to "Conquer City". The only current use of
>   "Destroy City" in the bundled rulesets is in the rulesets
>   webperimental and sandbox. There it is used to allow Leader (GameLoss)
>   units to order the razing of a domestic city. So a city must first be
>   conquered, then the Leader must move next to it, then the order to
>   raze the city must be given. Note that losing the Leader means game
>   over. Note that you can't build the Leader. You can get the Leader as
>   a start unit. The ruleset webperimental has Leader as a default start
>   unit.

(Posted by: Sveinung Kvilhaugsvik. Source: http://www.hostedredmine.com/issues/852312#note-3)